# Filter rows on inequality, case-insensitively

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following:

```
did_not_match = df[(df.old!=df.new)]
```

I am getting values that are still matching:

```
old     new
itest   iTest
```

How do update the code to account for capitalization, and get were `itest` and `iTest` are considered `!=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalise your strings, make them all uppercase, or all lowercase, all titlecase or capitalise them all, with the [`.str.upper()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html), [`.str.lower()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html), [`.str.title()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.title.html#pandas.Series.str.title) or [`.str.capitalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html#pandas.Series.str.capitalize) methods, before comparing:

```
did_not_match = df[df.old.str.upper() != df.new.str.upper()]
```

Pick one normalisation, and stick with it.

For more information on the string methods, see [*Working with Text Data*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html).